# I chose sass in angular CLI while i was creating the new project. i want to change it to scss now. how can i do that?

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

I need a step by step process to change SASS to SCSS in my angular project.I created a new project in angular. I was asked to chose any style sheet i want to use and i chose sass by mistake. while i was working on my project i realised it's sass and not SCSS. i want to use SCSS and i want to update that in my project. can you please tell me how to do that? i need step by step process.I tried to use few commands but then i started throwing error.

my angular.json file looks like this

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "wordle_app_ppl": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/wordle_app_ppl",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "wordle_app_ppl:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "wordle_app_ppl:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "wordle_app_ppl:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "wordle_app_ppl"
}
```

Comment: Change it where is says "style": "sass"

Answer (score 0):

Manually change in .angular.json:

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "styleext": "scss"
  }
}
```

Comment: i did that but then it throws error

```
"projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
```
as you can see styleext is throwing error. It says Property styleext is not allowed

Comment: i ran this command in command line 
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss but it throws the below error.
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "/schematics/@schematics~1angular:component" must NOT have additional properties(styleExt).

Comment: I have tried all these. That is Why i clearly mentioned in my question that i need a step by step process. if i change my style.sass to style.scss then also i am getting compilation error. Can someone please tell me every change to make in steps?